# Error Access forbidden

Tags: php, javascript, json, twitter, web

i encounter error on my php and i dont know what it is... it says "Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

twitter_sample.com
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7"

my code is

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{

  $file=$_FILES['media'];
  $postfields = array();

  $postfields['username'] = $_POST['username'];

  $postfields['password'] = $_POST['password'];
  $postfields['message'] = $_POST['message'];
  $postfields['media'] = "@$file[tmp_name]";

  $t=new twitpic($postfields,true,true);
  $t->post();
  exit;
}

?>

<style type="text/javascript">
  *{font-family:verdana;}
  span{font-size:12px;color:#393939;}
  h3{font-size:14px;color:#5AAAF7;}
</style>
<body>

  <h3>Upload your pic to twitpic, and post status on twitter</h3>
  <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>"   >
    <p><span style="height:40px;font-weight:bold;margin-right:56px;">Twitter Username :</span><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p><span style="height:40px;font-weight:bold;margin-right:61px;">Twitter Password:</span><input type="password" name="password" /></p>

    <p><span style="vertical-align:text-top;height:40px;font-weight:bold;margin-right:28px;">Message to be posted :</span> <textarea cols="35" rows="2" name="message"></textarea></p>
    <p><span style="vertical-align:text-top;height:40px;font-weight:bold;">Choose an image to upload: </span><input type="file" name="media" /></p>
    <p style="width:250px;text-align:right;margin-top:50px;"><input type="submit" value="Upload&nbsp;&raquo;" /> </p>
  </form>
  <sup>Script powered by <a href="http://www.digimantra.com/">www.digimantra.com</a></sup>
</body>

You can skip posting update to twitter by passing the third argument as false or just by skipping it. If you want to upload image programmatically, without the user input or the form then you can do it using the following code. Make sure the image path is correctly mention, else it will throw an error.

<?php
$file='file_to_be_uploaded.gif';
$postfields = array();

$postfields['username'] = 'twitter_username';

$postfields['password'] = 'twitter_password';
$postfields['message'] = 'Message to be posted' ;
$postfields['media'] = "@$file"; //Be sure to prefix @, else it wont upload

$t=new twitpic($postfields,true,true);
$t->post();
?>
```

and

```
<?php

class twitpic
{
  /* 
   * variable declarations
   */
  var $post_url='http://twitpic.com/api/upload';
  var $post_tweet_url='http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost';
  var $url='';
  var $post_data='';
  var $result='';
  var $tweet='';
  var $return='';

/*
* @param1 is the array of data which is to be uploaded
* @param2 if passed true will display result in the XML format, default is false
* @param3 if passed true will update status twitter,default is false
*/

  function __construct($data,$return=false,$tweet=false)
  {
    $this->post_data=$data;
    if(empty($this->post_data) || !is_array($this->post_data)) //validates the data
      $this->throw_error(0);
    $this->display=$return;
    $this->tweet=$tweet;

  }

  function post()
  {
    $this->url=($this->tweet)?$this->post_tweet_url:$this->post_url; //assigns URL for curl request based on the nature of request by user
    $this->makeCurl();
  }
  private function makeCurl()
  {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->post_data);
    $this->result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if($this->display)
    {
      header ("content-type: text/xml");
      echo $this->result ;
    }

  }
  private function throw_error($code) //handles few errors, you can add more

  {
    switch($code)
    {
      case 0:
        echo 'Think, you forgot to pass the data';
        break;
      default:
        echo 'Something just broke !!';
        break;
    }
    exit;
  }
} //class ends here

?>
```

Thank You...

Comment: There is probably an issue with your web server setup, and has nothing to do with your PHP scripts.

Comment: im running it in localhost... its that the problem?

Comment: This could be an issue with folder permissions- what web server are you using, and which folder are you serving the files from?

Comment: web server, is that xampp? coz im using xampp and my OS is windows7.

Comment: if you just have a normal html file, does that work through the web server?

Comment: should i change the (action="<?= $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>")?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the issue, but in localhost you must use:

$postfields['username'] =addslashes( $_POST['username'])

rather than

$postfields['username'] = $_POST['username']